# Getting years 2014+ from csv import to mysql

Tags: mysql, date, import

I used phpmyadmin for the csv import to mysql. The data contains date of birth (DOB). Some of the dates go over the current date. Ex: 2035-06-15. I am trying to find a way to fix it. Ex: 2035 to 1935. One approach is to UPDATE query all dates over the year 2013/2014. Is there a way I can make that a statement? I read around and heard that using wildcards for date types is a no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a wildcard, you can use the [`YEAR` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) to get the year:

```
YEAR(DOB)
```

Then you can use the [`DATE_SUB` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to subtract the 100 years:

```
DATE_SUB(DOB, INTERVAL 100 YEAR)
```

The whole query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET DOB = DATE_SUB(DOB, INTERVAL 100 YEAR)
WHERE YEAR(DOB) > 2013
```